# First order Logic find Model example

Tags: logic

Can anyone help my to find a model for this first order logic sentence?

1) dog doesn't bite dog

2) alf bites brick

3) brick bites alf

$\therefore$ 4) alf isn't a dog

now i have to negate the 4) and then find a model.

please can anyone help me?

Comment: You need two terms (i.e.names) for the dogs $alf$ and $brick$ and a binary relation $bites(x,y)$ meaning that "$x$ bites $y$". The only "hard" part is how to correctly formalize "dog doesn't bite dog" (you must use quantifiers).

Comment: This is my proposal : for 2) : $bites(alf, brick)$; for 3) : $bites(brick, alf)$; for 4) : $\lnot dog(alf)$, and its negation will be of course : $\lnot \lnot dog(alf)$, i.e. simply $dog(alf)$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the problem is relative to the relation of *logical entailment*, where we say that a set $\Gamma$ of sentences *entails* a sentence $\varphi$ (written $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$) when

> every interpretation that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ (also called a *model* of $\Gamma$) also satisfies $\varphi$.

The previous definition can be applied to prove that $\Gamma$ does **not** entails $\varphi$; to do this, it is enough to find a model of $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$ (if we find it, we call it a counter-example to the above entailment).

In our example, we have that $\Gamma = \{$ "dog doesn't bite dog", "alf bites brick", "brick bites alf" $\}$ and $\varphi$ is "alf isn't a dog".

We symbolize the sentences in the following manner :

> 2) is $bites(alf,brick)$
>
> 3) is $bites(brick,alf)$
>
> 4) is $\lnot dog(alf)$.

We have also 1), and we symbolize it as :

> 1) $\forall x [dog(x) \rightarrow \forall y (bites(x,y) \rightarrow \lnot dog(y))]$

i.e."if something is a dog and bites to some other thing, then this one is not a dog".

We need also the negation of 4); it will be of course : $\lnot \lnot dog(alf)$, i.e. simply $dog(alf)$.

Now, in order to show that $\Gamma$ does not entail $\varphi$ we search for a model of $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$.

*(i)* --- From 1), i.e. $\forall x [dog(x) \rightarrow \forall y (bites(x,y) \rightarrow \lnot dog(y))]$, we instantiate it wit $alf$ (because the initial universal quantifier says that the formula holds for everything; so we apply it to $alf$) and get :

> $dog(alf) \rightarrow \forall y (bites(alf,y) \rightarrow \lnot dog(y))$.

*(ii)* --- in our set of sentences $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$ we have the negation of 4), i.e. $dog(alf)$; so we use it to "detach" (i.e. we apply *modus ponens*) and obtain:

> $\forall y (bites(alf,y) \rightarrow \lnot dog(y))$.

*(iii)* --- We instantiate again using $brick$ and we have :

> $bites(alf,brick) \rightarrow \lnot dog(brick)$.

*(iv)* --- We apply again *modus ponens* using 2 and finally we have :

> $\lnot dog(brick)$.

Now we have found our model for $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$ : $dog(alf)$ and $\lnot dog(brick)$.

The sentences 1-3 do not entail 4 because, also if alf is a dog, it suffices that brick is not a dog to satisfy all them (i.e.$\Gamma$); and in this case $\varphi$ is not satisfied (because alf is a dog).